# Play Framework 2.1-RC1 Error value message is not a member of Option[play.api.data.FormError]

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I tried to upgrade Play 2.0 app to 2.1-RC1 and now it does not compile. I get the below error message:

```
value message is not a member of Option[play.api.data.FormError]
```

The line where above message is thrown is

```
<p class="error">@form.globalError.message</p>
```

Comment: did you import `helper` before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that in 2.1 `form.globalError` is an `Option`, so you'll need to do a `get` before accessing the `FormError`.

Something like:

```
@form.globalError.get.message
```

Be aware that could fail if the `Option` is `None`. Better use pattern matching or `getOrElse` to be safe.